# Вычислить сумму первых членов арифметической прогрессии

Tags: c, ряды

Задача вычислить сумму первых n-членов арифметической прогрессии по формуле  S=n/2*(a1+an)
Код выводит какой то непонятный результат.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double n ;
    double a1;
    double s ;
    double an ;
    printf("Enter n:\n");
    scanf("%1g", &n);
    printf("Enter a1:\n ");
        scanf("%1g", &a1);
        printf("Enter an");
        scanf("%1g", &an);
        s = (n / 2)*(a1 + an);
        printf("%1f\n",s);
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf("%1g", &n); А почему %1g, а не %f или %g просто?

кроме того лучше написать, что вводите и что считается (что выдается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в всех `scanf` должно быть `lg` или `lf` (там буква L, только в нижнем регистре). В противном случае, `scanf` считает, что там float и заполняет его неправильно.

А вот та единичка приводит ещё к одному интересному результату - будет считываться только один символ...